# Visual Studio 2013 MFC MBCS DLL Add-On Install Location

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, mbcs

I am currently migrating several projects from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013. These projects use MBCS for the character set and build fine on my local machine as I have installed the [MFC MBCS DLL Add-On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251007(v=vs.120).aspx).

The projects fail to build in Visual Studio 2013 on the build machines as the build machines do not have the MFC MBCS Add-On installed. Is it possible for the projects to build successfully on the build machine without installing the Add-On, but by including the dlls in the project additional include directories.

What is the install location of the MFC MBCS dlls?

Comment: The build system doesn't care about the DLLs. It's the import libraries that matter. Is there any reason for you to dismiss the solution to your problem?

Comment: Okay so I would need to install the Add-On onto the build machine for the projects to build. I wanted to see if there was an alternate solution, as I do not have access to change the build machines and the process to change them may take a while.

Comment: Of course there is an alternative solution: Upgrade your application to this millennium, and use Unicode. Other than those two options, there aren't any supported scenarios.

Comment: Well, if the people having access to the build-machines won't update it fast enough, go to their boss and give it a hour. If your company doesn't want to sell the product[s], then it'll need time. If you can upgrade to Unicode fast enough (less than 500k lines), go for that, it's better.

Comment: @Blacktempel: The total number of lines of a source base never been a reliable metric for ease or difficulty of implementing **any** given feature. You need to analyze the code to determine the cost and risk involved in moving to Unicode. And what's so special about 500k lines anyway?